# Unable to locate element - selenium webdriver python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, nosuchelementexception

So I tried to click a button using selenium webdriver in Python. It didn't find the element (in this case a class name), even with enough time to load the element.

I got this error:

`selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".account-item login-btn waves-effect"}`

here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

driver.get("https://freecash.com")
time.sleep(3)

signIn = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "account-item login-btn waves-effect")
signIn.click()
```

Please help me with this it would be greatly appreciated. If you need more info just ask down below. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To click on the element with text **Sign In** you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  driver.execute("get", {'url': 'https://freecash.com'})
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.account-item.login-btn span"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  driver.execute("get", {'url': 'https://freecash.com'})
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@class='account-item login-btn waves-effect']//span[text()='Sign In']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Wow, it works! Thank you very much. I tried using WebDriverWait earlier but it failed. I think I understand what I did wrong: seperating the waiting for element part from the finding the element part

Comment: Glad to be able to help you.